# Internet speed on Acer Aspire 5532 Slow

Tags: windows-7, wireless-networking, acer-aspire

Same network, My windows XP via Wireless download speed is 5.25-6 MB/s.  My sons laptop running Windows 7 home premium right next to my computer will only download a 1.72 Mb/s max.  I've updated wireless drivers to no avail?  Any help would be great
Acer-Aspire 5532 acer Nplify 802.11b/g/draft-n.  My router is new and is a N.

Answer (score 1):

I figured it out by my self.  The open network setting for my wireless router limits the speed of N cards to only 20% of my internet speed.  When I switched the Security to WEP2 the speed came back.  It looks like the router limits the N speed on open networks.  I have a G on my laptop and it was fine.  It only affected the N cards on my guests newer laptops.